# what will be the expression of this shifted cosine signal

Tags: signal-analysis, cosine

[image]

My solution is $y(t) = \cos(\omega t) + \frac{1}{2}$ giving it a shift of $\frac{1}{2}$
But I'm a bit skeptic about it, should there be any coefficient of cos to this modification?

Comment: Both X and Y Axis should have tick marls and proper labels. There appears to be a phase shift well but the way it is draw this is difficult to tell.  Is To supposed to be $T_0$  or does "To" stands for something else ?

Comment: @Hilmar it is $T_{o}$, and there is no phase shift. consider it as an ideal cosine signal. I'll update the tick marks but it just signifies the peaks..

Comment: thanks, that's much better. And yes, now your solution makes sense and is indeed correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct, as the cosine only has a DC shift, so only a constant value needs to be added to it.